# Merge two data frame based on ID column and condition on timestamp column

Tags: python, pandas

DataFrame1 had serial no which needs to be added to DataFrame2 based on “IP address” column. Which I can achieve by

> `df1.merge(df2, left_on='IPaddress', right_on='IPaddress')`

However, when merging I also need to consider the timestamp when that test occurred.
The scenarios are:

CASE1: For IP Address - 192.178.1.92, df1 has only one serial number. So, all the tests having IP address 192.178.1.92 should have Serial number as 8212. CASE2:

For IP Address - 192.178.1.90, df1 has only two serial numbers. So, the test2 should have serial number as 8227 while Test3 should have
8228. Serial Number (8227) was active till 7/4/2022  15:45:34 while serial number (8228) got active after 7/4/2022  15:45:35.

> CASE3: For IP Address - 192.178.1.94, df1 has only three serial
> > numbers. So, the test4 should have serial number as 8197, test5 should
> > have 8198, while Test6 should have 8199.

```
**df1:**
module  serial_no   IPaddress   datetime        
ABC 8212    192.178.1.92    7/4/2022 15:44:11       
PQR 8227    192.178.1.90    7/4/2022 13:10:20
PQR 8228    192.178.1.90    7/4/2022 15:45:35       
XYZ 8197    192.178.1.94    7/4/2022 13:09:09       
XYZ 8198    192.178.1.94    7/4/2022 15:45:53       
XYZ 8199    192.178.1.94    7/4/2022 17:33:42       

**df2:**
Test    IPaddress   datetime
Test1   192.178.1.92    7/4/2022 21:44:11
Test2   192.178.1.90    7/4/2022 14:25:18
Test3   192.178.1.90    7/4/2022 15:45:35
Test4   192.178.1.94    7/4/2022 13:09:09
Test5   192.178.1.94    7/4/2022 15:45:53
Test6   192.178.1.94    7/4/2022 17:33:42

**Output:**
Test    IPaddress        datetime           SLNO  Module
Test1   192.178.1.92    7/4/2022 21:44:11   8212    ABC
Test2   192.178.1.90    7/4/2022 14:25:18   8227    PQR
Test3   192.178.1.90    7/4/2022 15:45:35   8228    PQR
Test4   192.178.1.94    7/4/2022 13:09:09   8197    XYZ
Test5   192.178.1.94    7/4/2022 15:45:53   8198    XYZ
Test6   192.178.1.94    7/4/2022 17:33:42   8199    XYZ
```

Comment: I feel like you should not do the merge on "IPaddress". If order is meaning, you should join on index, or you could also join using datetime which would seem more appropriate here.

Comment: Benjamin, Thank you for the reply. I was able to solve the problem.
In the Df1, I created new column to identify Start and End Time. 
After that using pandasql I merged the two dataframe to get the required result.